# mandar a otra ventana el resultado del lector de Código QR

Tags: javascript, php, qrcode

Hola tengo un lector de códigos qr con la librería html5-qrcode y funciona correctamente, la cosa es que como soy nuevo todavía, me cuesta recolectar y mandar variables de una pagina a otra, entonces lo que estoy tratando de hacer y no he podido, es que el resultado del  scaner, poderlo mandar a otra pagina para poder utilizar ese resultado para compararlo con un campo de la bd, este es el código:

```
function comparar(/*decodeText*/) {

   /*
    Swal.fire({
        title: "Escaneo exitoso",
        text: "El codigo "+decodeText+ " se encuentra en la Base de datos",
        icon: 'success',
        confirmButtonColor: '#FFC100',
        confirmButtonText: 'Ir a la hoja de vida',
    }).then((result) => {
        
    })*/
    var resultado = $('#resultado').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "Hojas_Vida.php",
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            resultado:resultado
        },
        success: function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
        }
    })
}
var resultContainer = document.getElementById('qr-reader-results');
var lastResult, countResults = 0;

function onScanSuccess(decodedText, decodedResult) {
    if (decodedText !== lastResult) {
        ++countResults;
        var decode = decodedText;
        // Handle on success condition with the decoded message.
        console.log(`Resultado del escaner: ${decodedText}`);
        $('#resultado').val(decodedText);
        comparar(/*decodedText*/);
        

        /*window.location = base_url + "Hojas_Vida/hojas?decode='"+$decodedText+"' "; */
        /* window.location = base_url + "Hojas_Vida/hojas?decode='+$decodedText+'";*/
    }
}

var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
    "qr-reader", {
        fps: 10,
        qrbox: 250
    });
html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess);
</script>
```

Este es el codigo del controlador de php que se llama Hojas_Vida.php

```
public function Consultarcodigo(){
    $resultado = $_POST['resultado'];
    $data = $this->model->getConsultar($resultado);
    if($resultado == $data){
        echo $data; //igual si sigues mi ejemplo
        // echo 'http://commons.wikimedia.org/' // asi quedaria usando el tuyo
    }
    else{
        echo $data;
    }
}
```

Este es el codigo del modelo

```
/*Funcion para consultar los codigos para el escaner */
public function getConsultar(string $resultado){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM hojas_vida  where codigo = $resultado";
    $data =$this->selectAll($sql);
    return $data;
}
```

Y este es el codigo de la vista

```
<div id="qr-reader" class="mb-5"></div>
<div id="qr-reader-results"></div>
<input type="text" id="resultado" value="" style="background-color:white !important; width:200px; height:50px;">
```

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta es original en Ingles, y la traducción a dañado el código en unas partes.. Santiago, creo que si la haces en [https://stackoverflow.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/) tendrás mejores resultados.

Comment: Hola! Asumo que tu variable "resultContainer" almacena lo que te devuelve la lectura del QR. Si es así, lo que puedes hacer es enviar ese dato por AJAX a otro archivo PHP en donde ya puedes compararlo con los datos que traes de tu BD.

Comment: no he intentando mandar la respuesta con esa respuesta, pero ya lo voy a intentar pero no deberia que ser la que dice decoderesult ya que es el resultado decoficado y el containerresult es el dato que el trae y al ser el valor que decodificado no es ese el que se deberia que enviar?

Comment: En el modelo, prueba hacer un return $sql y mira si la consulta que te imprime en consola está bien... Prueba la consulta a ver si a nivel de BD está bien hecha

Comment: me dice que no existe el controlador

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Crear un input que almacene el valor que devuelve al leer el QR. Ejemplo:
   `<input type="text" id="resultado" value="">`
2. Al ejecutarse la función `onScanSuccess`, obtienes el valor que trae la variable `decodedText` y se lo asignas al value del input que previamente habías creado.

Esta sería más o menos la idea del código:

```
    <div id="qr-reader" class="mb-5"></div>
     <div id="qr-reader-results"></div>
    <input type="text" id="resultado" value="">
    
    <script src=" https://unpkg.com/html5-qrcode" tipo=" texto/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function comparar()
        {
            var resultado = $('#resultado').val();
            $.ajax({
                url:"nombre_de_tu_archivo.php",
                method:'POST',
                data:{resultado:resultado}, //Variable que debes recibir en PHP como $_POST['resultado']
                success:function(resp)
                {
                    if(resp == 'igual') //En este caso 'igual' es el echo que retorna el PHP, si la consulta se ejecuta bien y coinciden, imprimes el echo 'igual'
                    {
                        alert('Son iguales!');
                        $("#resultado").val('');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert('Son diferentes!');
                        $("#resultado").val('');
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            var resultContainer = document.getElementById('qr-reader-results');
            var lastResult, countResults = 0;
    
            function onScanSuccess(decodedText, decodedResult) {
                if (decodedText !== lastResult) {
                    ++countResults;
                    console.log(`Resultado del escaner: ${decodedText}`); //imprimes en consola para asegurarte que no está vacío
                    $('#resultado').val(decodedText); //Asignas la respuesta al input que habías creado
                    comparar(); //llamas la función donde está tu ajax
                }
            }
    
            var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
                "qr-reader", {
                    fps: 10,
                    qrbox: 250
                });
            html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess);
        });
    </script>
```

Este sería el archivo PHP:

```
<?php
    $resultado = $_POST['resultado'];
    $result_bd = $campo_de_tu_base_de_datos;

    if($resultado == $result_bd){
        echo 'igual'; //igual si sigues mi ejemplo
        // echo 'http://commons.wikimedia.org/' // asi quedaria usando el tuyo
    }
    else{
        echo 'diferentes';
    }
?>
```

Ajax entiende "solo" que el echo es la respuesta que tiene que usar, yo en el ejemplo la llamo como "resp"

Comment: voy aintentar muchisimas gracias

Comment: acabo de probar el codigo y me manda al condicional de no son iguales lo aplique como me dijo a excepcion de el document.ready ya que si ingresaba el escaner asi desaparecia como que afectaba la estructura de la libreria asi quedo el codigo

Answer (score 0):

El codigo quedo asi, nose mucho de ajax asi que no se si cometi algo mal
el enlace de wikipedia ps es el valor del codigo qr por eso me parece raro que diga que son diferentes

```
<script>

    function comparar(){
            var resultado = $('#resultado').val();
            $.ajax({
                url:"Hojas_Vida/hojas.php",
                method:'POST',
                data:{resultado:resultado},
                success:function(resp)
                {
                    if(resp == 'http://commons.wikimedia.org/')
                    {
                        alert('Son iguales!');
                        $("#resultado").val('');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert('Son diferentes!');
                        $("#resultado").val('');
                    }
                }
            })
    }

var resultContainer = document.getElementById('qr-reader-results');
var lastResult, countResults = 0;

function onScanSuccess(decodedText, decodedResult) {
    if (decodedText !== lastResult) {
        ++countResults;
        var decode = decodedText;
        // Handle on success condition with the decoded message.
        console.log(`Resultado del escaner: ${decodedText}`);
        $('#resultado').val(decodedText);
        comparar(); 

        /*window.location = base_url + "Hojas_Vida/hojas?decode='"+$decodedText+"' "; */
       /* window.location = base_url + "Hojas_Vida/hojas?decode='+$decodedText+'";*/
    }
}

var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
    "qr-reader", {
        fps: 10,
        qrbox: 250
    });
html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess);
```

Comment: ¿Es esto una respuesta o una continuación de tu pregunta? De ser lo segundo, borra esta _no-respuesta_, y edita tu pregunta.

Comment: El resultado en consola te imprime lo que esperabas? Puedes mostrar también cómo tienes el PHP?

Comment: es la respuesta

Comment: si por supuesto en consola me imprime la lectura y en php no tengo nada lo que he intentado apenas es que me mande nomas el valor todavia no tengo nada para que me compare si es igual solo estoy trattando de que me mande el valor

Comment: Por eso te tira que son diferentes, las alertas de "Son iguales o Son diferentes" dependen de lo que reciba el AJAX del archivo PHP. En el archivo PHP recibe la variable con $_POST y compárala con la que tengas en tu BD, si son iguales haz un echo con la URL (así como lo tienes en el if del AJAX)

Comment: ok ya voy a intentar pero una pregunta aca que iria    if(resp == 'igual')
 en las comillas que pondria y perdon la ignorancia que variable llamo en php con el post

Comment: Revisa de nuevo el código, agregué un par de comentarios que te pueden ayudar

Comment: Agregué también un ejemplo de cómo sería mas o menos el PHP, si tienes más dudas puedes preguntar :)

Comment: acabo de intentarlo de esta manera acabo de actualizar el codigo de como quedo pero me sigue arrojando que son diferentes

Comment: Guarda la consulta en una variable, en el echo del PHP imprime esa variable y luego muéstrala en consola con JS, así puedes saber qué está consultando la consulta y ver si es lo que esperas

Comment: no me esta consultando nada o sera que estoy imprimiendo mal en js en el controlador ps normal guardo la consulta que es data en una variable y la mando por el echo y ps con la misma logia del igual  hago esto 
        success: function(resp) {
            console.log(resp); quito el condicional y la variable que es resp la imprimo

Comment: Por lo que dices parece que estás imprimiendo bien en el JS, el problema parecería ser el PHP. Puedes ir editando tu código en la pregunta para poder ayudarte, sino es algo complicado

Comment: listo ya lo edite